# How to build thrift .lib for Universal Window Application

Tags: c++, mfc, win-universal-app

Before I have built thrift .lib for MFC c++ project. Now we want to clone project to UWP app. So we need to rebuild thrift for UWP app.

I got thrift C++ source code from apache site: http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/thrift/0.9.3/thrift-0.9.3.tar.gz. And try to rebuild it follow the guide in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt186162.aspx **To port a C++ library to a Windows Runtime Component**.

fixed some error but some error I don't know how to fix, such as:

Error   C3861   'PeekNamedPipe': identifier not found   EvernoteThrift  d:\evernotethrift\src\thrift\transport\tpipe.cpp    87
Error   C3861   'CreateFile': identifier not found  EvernoteThrift  d:\evernotethrift\src\thrift\transport\tpipe.cpp    108 
Error   C3861   'SetNamedPipeHandleState': identifier not found EvernoteThrift  d:\evernotethrift\src\thrift\transport\tpipe.cpp    127

I think the cause of these error is Window Runtime can not use some Win32 API. I googled but haven't found solution. Could any one know about this ?

I don't understand deeply about thrift, just want to build and use it as lib :(